# np.isnan() == False, but np.isnan() is not False

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, python-3.5

As far as I understand it, `==` checks for equality of value, and `is` checks for identity of structure behind value (as, say `===` in some other languages).

Given that, I don't understand the following:

```
np.isnan(30) == False
Out[19]: 
True
np.isnan(30) is False
Out[20]: 
False
```

It appears not to be the case with other identity checks:

```
(5 == 4) == False
Out[22]: 
True
(5 == 4) is False
Out[23]: 
True
```

It appears as if `np.isnan()` returns `False` as a value, but not as identity. Why is that the case?

Comment: You should never test for `False` or `True` in the first place. Use `if np.isnan(..)` and `if not np.isnan(..)`. There is no requirement that the Python interpreter only ever uses 1 copy of the boolean value objects, evidently Numpy doesn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that appears rather to be a style comment (which I appreciate), but not as the answer to the behavior of the function?

Comment: (That is, while I *should* not do that operation, I *should be able to* do it. no?)

Comment: @FooBar it's entirely implementation-dependent whether that is the case, so *no*, you *shouldn't* be able to do it.

Comment: ... or rather, this behaviour is a direct demonstration of why you should not do it.

Comment: @FooBar: Nowhere in the Python language spec is it stated that `True` and `False` can be considered singletons. Don't rely on the behaviour.

Comment: Re your question `numpy` has its own `dtypes`. So a `np.bool` is not the same as a plain Python `bool`

Comment: `np.False_ ` appears to have a different identity from `False` in native Python; it's probably an implementation detail though

Comment: @kojiro You realize he edited that in later, right?

Comment: @PaulPanzer If you put that in as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @FooBar seems I've been beaten to it...

Answer (score 10):

`numpy.isnan()` returns a **compatible** type object:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> type(numpy.isnan(0))
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

This is a custom boolean that can be stored efficiently in numpy arrays, see [Numpy's *Data Types* documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#id1). The `numpy.isnan()` function can also operate on arrays, producing another array with results:

```
>>> numpy.isnan(numpy.array([1, 2]))
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

where again the `dtype` is the Numpy boolean object.

Python makes no guarantees that boolean operations must always return a singleton boolean value. You should never test for `is True` or `is False` *anyway*. Use `numpy.isnan()` output directly in boolean operations, use `not` to test for false values:

```
if numpy.isnan(foo):
```

and

```
if not numpy.isnan(bar):
```

Comment: This turned out to be a fascinating foray. I discovered that numpy also has a `bool` function that is the same as `builtins.bool`. *scratches head*. So `numpy.bool_` is numpy's bool, but `numpy.bool` is Python's bool.

Comment: @kojiro: that's.. probably a leaked global.

Comment: So say we `__all__`.

Comment: @kojiro: [this line imports it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L176). Not sure why they feel the need to make those accessible. Perhaps legacy support, where previously the dtypes were available under those names. There's no explanation in the [original commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/762dacd686faa83c7de12c115e0a5874eef0481e).

Comment: Legacy, indeed. At first `numpy.bool` was the numpy scalar type, but it was renamed to `numpy.bool_` fairly quickly after it was pointed out that this would override the builtin when `from numpy import *` was done (was more common back then). But by then there was already code using `dtype=numpy.bool`, etc. So the name remains, just as recapitulations of the builtins.

Answer (score 3):

`np.isnan(30)` `return`s `np.False_` which has a different identity from `False`; don't rely on this though.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.isnan(30) is np.False_
True
>>> np.False_ is False
False
>>>
```